# How can I extract only USD values from a column in R data table including salaries in crore?

Tags: r

I have a table with data for the ongoing IPL 2023, with includes a list of the players' salaries. The salaries are either written in the forms, for example, "₹6.75 crore (US$850,000)", "₹50 lakh (US$63,000)", or ₹16 crore (US$2.0 million)". I want to only extract the USD value (if it's listed in millions, I want to have the full number, i.e 2.0 milllion should be 2,000,000).

```r
ipl_2023_salaries <- read_excel(file_path)

usd_values <- str_extract_all(ipl_2023_salaries$Salary, "\\(US\\$([0-9.,]+)\\)")   

usd_values <- sapply(usd_values, function(x) ifelse(length(x) > 0, gsub("[^0-9.]", "", x), NA))   

ipl_2023_salaries$Salary <- as.numeric(usd_values)

print(ipl_2023_salaries)
```

I expected this code to give me the output I desired, but instead every salary value is now NA.

Comment: Can you please share some example data (ideally using `dput()`) as it would allow others to run your code?

Answer (score 1):

Split strings at `$`, pass 2nd part to `readr::parse_number()` and if there's a match for *"million"*, multiply by *1e6*:

```r
library(stringr)
library(readr)
salary <- c("₹6.75 crore (US$850,000)", "₹50 lakh (US$63,000)", "₹16 crore (US$2.0 million)")
parse_number(str_split_i(salary, "\\$", 2)) * ifelse(str_detect(salary, "\\$.*million"),1e6,1)
#> [1]  850000   63000 2000000
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>